# How to Break <OBJECT DATA> Frame

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

i would like to say first that i am not a developer i am a graphic designer.

I am trying to load an external page inside a div below the code:

```
<div id="gallerycontainer"></div>​
<script src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.7.2.min.js"></script>
<script>
  $("#gallerycontainer").html('<object data="Gallery/Gallery.html" width="680" height="280">');
</script></div>
```

my page contains a lightbox, i want the lightbox to bread the frame and open on the main parent page.

Please advise if possible.